# Add Employee to Quick book and Set Time status value to false Quick book using QBSDK 10.0

Tags: c#, quickbooks

I am trying to add Employee.I need to set value for "IsUsingTimeDataToCreatePaychecks" because if I am not set that value and try to create time tracking for that Employee it give me Error "3310 Unknown employee time status Failed to save the T".I have used following Code to create Employee.

```
public class Sample
{
    public void DoEmployeeAdd()
    {
        bool sessionBegun = false;
        bool connectionOpen = false;
        QBSessionManager sessionManager = null;

        try
        {
            //Create the session Manager object
            sessionManager = new QBSessionManager();

            //Create the message set request object to hold our request
            IMsgSetRequest requestMsgSet = sessionManager.CreateMsgSetRequest("US",10, 0);
            requestMsgSet.Attributes.OnError = ENRqOnError.roeContinue;

            BuildEmployeeAddRq(requestMsgSet);

            //Connect to QuickBooks and begin a session
            sessionManager.OpenConnection("", "SampleTest");
            connectionOpen = true;
            sessionManager.BeginSession("", ENOpenMode.omDontCare);
            sessionBegun = true;

            //Send the request and get the response from QuickBooks
            IMsgSetResponse responseMsgSet = sessionManager.DoRequests(requestMsgSet);

            //End the session and close the connection to QuickBooks
            sessionManager.EndSession();
            sessionBegun = false;
            sessionManager.CloseConnection();
            connectionOpen = false;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Error");
            if (sessionBegun)
            {
                sessionManager.EndSession();
            }
            if (connectionOpen)
            {
                sessionManager.CloseConnection();
            }
        }
    }


    void BuildEmployeeAddRq(IMsgSetRequest requestMsgSet)
    {
        try
        {
            IEmployeeAdd EmployeeAddRq = requestMsgSet.AppendEmployeeAddRq();

            EmployeeAddRq.IsActive.SetValue(true);

            EmployeeAddRq.Salutation.SetValue("Mr");

            EmployeeAddRq.FirstName.SetValue("Prashant");

            EmployeeAddRq.MiddleName.SetValue("A");

            EmployeeAddRq.LastName.SetValue("Patel");

            EmployeeAddRq.EmployeeAddress.Addr1.SetValue("20,Hari Hari");

            EmployeeAddRq.EmployeeAddress.Addr2.SetValue("ab");

            EmployeeAddRq.EmployeeAddress.City.SetValue("Surat");

            EmployeeAddRq.EmployeeAddress.State.SetValue("CA");

            EmployeeAddRq.EmployeeAddress.PostalCode.SetValue("395004");

            EmployeeAddRq.EmployeeType.SetValue(ENEmployeeType.etOfficer);



            EmployeeAddRq.HiredDate.SetValue(DateTime.Parse("12/15/2014"));

            EmployeeAddRq.ReleasedDate.SetValue(DateTime.Parse("12/15/2014"));

            EmployeeAddRq.BirthDate.SetValue(DateTime.Parse("12/15/2014"));

            EmployeeAddRq.EmployeePayrollInfo.IsUsingTimeDataToCreatePaychecks.SetValue(true);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }

}
```

but this code give me "This feature is not supported in the specified version of qbXML. at QBFC10Lib.IEmployeePayrollInfo.get_IsUsingTimeDataToCreatePaychecks() at SampleTimeSheet.Sample.BuildEmployeeAddRq(IMsgSetRequest requestMsgSet)" Exception.How can I resolve this issue?I am using QBSDK 10.0 and my quick book version is 2014 accountant copy.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

`EmployeePayrollInfo.UseTimeDataToCreatePaychecks.SetValue(ENUseTimeDataToCreatePaychecks.utdtcpUseTimeData);`

instead of

`EmployeePayrollInfo.IsUsingTimeDataToCreatePaychecks.SetValue(true);`

For some reason the "IsUsing" option hasn't been implemented and you'll get the error that it's not supported, but the "Use" does work. This is both for QBFC as well as QBXML.